# i get timeout error while adding mail account in mailenable mail server

Tags: iis, timeout, fastcgi

i want to add a mailenable mail account via php-IIS-plesk 
i load two COM object : "MEAOPO.MailBox" and "MEAOAU.Login" 
i give iis and website user full permissions to execute dlls folder of mailenable and modify mailoffices , config folder 
but still get 500 error 
**The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout** 
the point in error page is: 
**Logon Method     Anonymous 
Logon User     Anonymous** 
it seems NTFS permission issue ...

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is ok, maybe your php application server truly runs out of time. In some cases it could take up to two minutes to create a new mailbox with MEAOPO classes. If not already set, try to rise scripting timeout with something like
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes